# get request error in python 3.7, max tries exceeded

Tags: python, download, get

I've been trying to develop a bat to help a tidios task in my job and in order to do that I fisrtly need to download a document from a government website, with that said my first attempt was something like this

```
    import requests

    url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php"

    response = requests.get(url)

    url - open("teste.zip", "w")
    url.write(response.content)
    url.close()
```

but i kept getting this error message:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='servicos.ibama.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F00E873048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

then I thought that the problem might be that I was sennding to many requests at the same time to the server and it was denying it for that reason, so I changed my code to this:

```
    import requests
    import time

    url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php"

    page = ''
    while page == '':
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            break
        except:
            print("Connection refused by the server..")
            time.sleep(3)

            continue

    url - open("teste.zip", "w")
    url.write(response.content)
    url.close()
```

and what I got was an endless loop. I checked the URL and it still works, althoug it says that the connection is not safe, that might be a reason for this issue but I do not know how to overcome it, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This one work fine in **Python 2.7**

```
import urllib2
import ssl
url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php"
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=context)
file = open("test.zip", 'w')
data = response.read()
file.write(data)
file.close()
```